# What is the use of callback in MQTT?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, iot

I am trying to implement a weather monitoring system using Arduino and MQTT protocol. While trying to understand the code behind this, I have come across a function:

```
void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
}
```

So, my question is, what exactly is this function used for in MQTT? If someone explains to me or links a tutorial that will be useful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Asking for links to tutorials is off topic for Stack Overflow. Have you looked at the documentation for the library you are using, it is likely to have a description of the `callback` function

Answer (score 0):

This function is called by the underlying MQTT library when a new message is received from the broker (for a topic you have subscribed to).

It is up to you to fill in the detail of how you want to process the message.